# SOQL: Get Most Recent Child of Parent

Tags: soql

I need select the Email off the most recently created Contact for all of my Accounts to export via the Data Loader. So far I have this but then I'm stuck. I keep thinking of functions like MAX(CreatedDate) but how the might help me just isn't turning on a light bulb, any ideas?

```
SELECT Email from Contact where Account in (Select Id from Account) Order By CreatedDate
```

Comment: Does select top works in Dataloader?

Comment: As in: `SELECT TOP 5 Email From Contact`?
No, but could do this: `SELECT Email from Contact limit 5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List <Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Email FROM Contacts ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account];
```

Then you can use:

```
for(Account acc : accounts)
{
    if(acc.Contacts.size() > 0)
        String accountEmail = acc.Contacts[0].Email;
        // do whatever you need to do with the email...
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified, I need to do this for the dataloader and not in APEX, so I can't have nested queries in the select clause.

Comment: That approach would work on workbench.developerforce.com (just the query that is, you might also be able to export the results as CSV from there)